SSL HTTP Validation Request returns a 404 although exists
CPanels AutoSSL Feature does run a Domain Validation Request via HTTP to check if an acme challenge text file is existent but it reports a 404 not found. When I manually add a html file in this dir I got also 404. I have seen this behaviour with mod_security but I disabled the entire module (and the FW as well) - still no success. This is the error I am getting, server is running up to date WHM/CPanel + Almalinux 8:
MASTER DCV: 403 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized (The client lacks sufficient authorization) (94.36.10.23: Invalid response from h t t p://abc.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/gnUpIld2fDbJVDvSWa9MTZjQSDw3wc27YwEygJEGX9Y: 404) 400 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns (There was a problem with a DNS query) (DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.abc.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain)

Certbot Output, AutoSSL reports the same:
"
Requesting a certificate for abc.com and www.abc.com
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
Domain: www.abc.com
Type:   dns
Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.abc.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain; DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for www.abc.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain
Domain: abc.com
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: 94.36.10.23: Invalid response from h t t p://abc.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/QUHWPdkws3Wy4tFKRbvzr9Mayih-3HCJo7-yCkhALKI: 404
Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet."

Maybe this blog post is of any help? https://ofaolain.com/blog/2020/09/24/when-autossl-wont-renew-lets-encrypt/
It mentions three possible problems: 1) insufficient permissions 2) .htaccess redirects 3) Cloudflare Proxy

Thank you very much but tried all this before, no cloudflare using (at least not that I am aware of).

or your webserver (Apache?) has some special configuration regarding the „/.well-known“ path or paths starting with a dot? see https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/apache-well-known-404/183838
